# singly connected line in the plane

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

point $X_A \ $ and $ X_B \ $ is located in the same plane.
$$\widehat {\bf x} =  \lambda {\bf x_A} + (1 - \lambda){\bf x_B}$$
can someone explain about this equation more?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: It means $\hat X$ is all the elements that you can get by this equation (normally either $\lambda \in [0,1]$ or $\mathbb R$) with vectors $X_A$ and $X_B$. You will see this is either the line between/through these to points/vectors.

Comment: As $\lambda$ varies between $0$ and $1$, $\widehat {\bf x}$ varies linearly between ${\bf x_A}$ and ${\bf x_B}$. By "linearly" I mean that the point is the same fraction of the way between the  endpoints as the parameter is between $0$ and $1$. The parameter can, of course, move outside of the range $[0,1]$, in which case the point will continue to move linearly outside of the segment between the endpoints. As others have indicated, it moves along the line determined by the two endpoints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is general equation for all points on the line through $X_A$ and $X_B$. If $\lambda \in [0,1]$, then it represents segment $\overline{X_AX_B}$ and if $\lambda $ is arbitrary, then it represents line.

For example,

when $\lambda = 0$, $\hat x=X_B$

when $\lambda = 1$, $\hat x = X_A$

when $\lambda = 0.5$, $\hat x$ is midpoint of segment $\overline{X_AX_B}$.